# SQLAlchemy relationship list for each row in query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

MODELS:

```
class Post(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    topics = relationship('PostTopic', back_populates='post')

class PostTopic(Base):
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("post.id"), primary_key=True)
    topic_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("topic.id"), primary_key=True)
    topic = relationship('Topic', foreign_keys=topic_id,
                     back_populates="posts_per_topic")
    post = relationship('Post',
                     foreign_keys=post_id,
                     back_populates="topics")

class Topic(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    topic_name = Column(Text)
    posts_per_topic = relationship('PostTopic', back_populates='topic')
```

I'm trying to query a list of entities from posts, and with each post, a list of the one to many topic_names all in one query.

```
post_bundle = Bundle('post', Post.id, Post.title, Post.image, Post.date_created)
creator_bundle = Bundle('user', User.first_name, User.last_name, User.photo_link, User.user_id)
subject_bundle = Bundle('subject', Subject.icon)
topic_bundle = Bundle('topic', Topic.topic_name)

return request.dbsession.query(post_bundle, creator_bundle, subject_bundle, topic_bundle)\
        .join(Post.creator, Post.subject)\
        .join("topics", "topic")\
        .filter(Post.is_archived == False, Post.is_draft == False)\
        .filter(User.is_banned == False)
```

But I'm receiving repeats for the same post for each topic.
eg.

```
('post_title_1', 'topic_title_1'),
('post_title_1', 'topic_title_2'),
('post_title_1', 'topic_title_3'),
('post_title_1', 'topic_title_4'),
```

What I want:

```
('post_title_1', ('topic_title_1', 'topic_title_2', 'topic_title_3', )),    
('post_title_2', ('topic_title_4', 'topic_title_5', 'topic_title_6', )),
```

Comment: Out of interest, why are you using [bundles](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#column-bundles) instead of the mapped classes? The latter would allow "deduplicating" through eager loads. The repeats you're observing with your current approach is just how SQL works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform those results with a small loop like:

#### Code:

```
titles = {}
for post, topic in data:
    titles.setdefault(post, []).append(topic)
new_data = list(titles.items())
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = (
    ('post_title_1', 'topic_title_1'),
    ('post_title_1', 'topic_title_2'),
    ('post_title_1', 'topic_title_3'),
    ('post_title_2', 'topic_title_4'),
    ('post_title_2', 'topic_title_5'),
    ('post_title_2', 'topic_title_6'),
)
print(data)

titles = {}
for post, topic in data:
    titles.setdefault(post, []).append(topic)
new_data = list(titles.items())
print(new_data)
```

#### Results:

```
(
    ('post_title_1', 'topic_title_1'), 
    ('post_title_1', 'topic_title_2'), 
    ('post_title_1', 'topic_title_3'), 
    ('post_title_2', 'topic_title_4'), 
    ('post_title_2', 'topic_title_5'), 
    ('post_title_2', 'topic_title_6')
)

[
    ('post_title_1', ['topic_title_1', 'topic_title_2', 'topic_title_3']),
    ('post_title_2', ['topic_title_4', 'topic_title_5', 'topic_title_6'])
]
```

Comment: `defaultdict(list)` makes for a nice alternative to `setdefault`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, Thanks for the note.  But I am not a big fan of defaultdict.  It requires an additional import and in some timing tests I did, for simple default objects, can be slower that `setdefault`.

Comment: Performance testing's a funny thing, I've had the opposite results :P. Depends on the use case I'd wager.